# PSPP has no dedicated tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-proposal

A meta question: how come https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPP has no tag of its own? Its users are more command line driven than `SPSS` users which are more GUI driven. As a result `PSPP` has another kind of questions. How (and who?) to convince to create a dedicated `PSPP` tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You can create new tags yourself if you have at least 300 reputation.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) For now, I [searched for questions containing "PSPP"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=PSPP+is%3Aq) and added a [pspp](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pspp) tag. (More precisely, [Kjetil](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/11887/kjetil-b-halvorsen) seems to have been doing the work while I was talking about it.)

I also created a rudimentary [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/pspp/info). Any improvement would be most welcome.